# Is it by any means premature to put the title of your thesis in resume?

Tags: thesis, cv, bachelor

This summer I’ll be graduating with a BSc in Computer Science: would it by any means premature and childish to put now the title of my thesis in a resume under a specific education accomplishment?

Comment: I removed the image because it was not relevant for the question, and moreover it wasn’t clear whether it really represented your situation. I also adjusted the phrasing to make it clearer the sequence of events. Let me know if I’ve got the situation right.

Comment: Your undergraduate thesis, which you have started already? Sure, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to put "work in progress" into a CV. Just mark it as such, since it isn't yet "accomplished work. Usually a separate section for such things is good to have.

You can do the same for other, not yet completed, projects.

Make it clear and it is fine.

It is a bit harder to justify if you haven't yet started, but even that can be marked as "future directions" or such.

Comment: You don't consider this "immature" or "premature" to do, given that my resume is 1 page only currently?

Comment: Not at all. You've got to start somewhere.

Comment: @AlixBlaine - the last resume I put together was one page, excluding the list of publications. I’m likely never writing another one before retiring, but I hate long resumes that don’t focus on the job one is applying for. I say that as someone who regularly hires for PhD staff and other positions. An undergraduate should have a one page resume.

Comment: @JonCuster, WOW! Interesting. To you, what would it mean, if a person has a piece of written article published at some big name company?

Comment: @AlixBlaine - depends on the job one is applying for. An undergraduate doing a thesis is not unusual, a journal article is a bonus. Masters and PhDs I'd expect journal articles. But just counting articles is far from what I do...

Comment: Big name as **Microsoft**!